# Gpu passthrough unable to blacklist drivers?

Tags: drivers, virtualization, gpu

I am by no means "good" at Linux but I have been trying to set up a Windows virtual machine with a GPU passthrough. Now I only have one GPU but from my reading it seems possible?

My current hardware set up is:

- HDMI into monitor one from motherboard
- VGA into monitor 2 from motherboard
- HDMI into monitor one from my GPU (amd r9 280)

I have been following this [guide](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Multiheaded-NVIDIA-Gaming-using-Ubuntu-14-04-KVM-585/). I am all fine until I have to blacklist my my GPU drivers.

This is the output of `lspci -nn`:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tahiti PRO [Radeon HD 7950/8950 OEM / R9 280] [1002:679a]

01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tahiti XT HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7970 Series] [1002:aaa0]
```

Following the guide I edited `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` to add 
`pci_stub ids=1002:679a,1002:aaa0`.

After updating it and rebooting this is the output of `dmesg | grep pci-stub`:

```
*[ 3.784506] pci-stub: add 1002:679A sub=FFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFF cls=00000000/00000000

[3.784509] pci-stub: add 1002:AAA0 sub=FFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFF cls=00000000/00000000

[ 3.784515] pci-stub 0000:01:00.1: claimed by stub*
```

Only my audio driver is being stubbed, not my main video driver.
Any help would be absoloutely great, as I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the GPU. But from [this post](http://www.bnote.us/2015/04/kvm-vga-passthrough-in-ubuntu-1504-vivid.html), I learned that I had to manually add the device in the blacklist.conf.

First open

```
sudo mousepad /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

And add

```
blacklist radeon
```

And lastly,

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Hope that helps.